# phantomjs with non-english url

Tags: python, phantomjs

in querystring part of my url passing to phantomjs in python, I have values in persian language. But after capturing the result using driver.save_screenshot('screen.png'), I see the querystring did not apply.
Actually it's a search page and it returns no result.
By removing the persian querystring, with other part of querystring which is numbers, everything is ok.
This  does not work :

[http://codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?1=خودرو&2=&3=&4=-1&5=&6=&7=&8=-1&9=12&10=-1&11=1395%2f12%2f29&12=False&13=0](http://codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?1=%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88&2=&3=&4=-1&5=&6=&7=&8=-1&9=12&10=-1&11=1395%2f12%2f29&12=False&13=0)

And this works:

http://codal.ir/ReportList.aspx?2=&3=&4=-1&5=&6=&7=&8=-1&9=12&10=-1&11=1395%2f12%2f29&12=False&13=0

Answer (score 1):

Try using escaped string instead of raw persian characters:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.quote('خودرو')
'%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88'
```

This MAY fix your problem.